# Angular - How to invoke function from parent to child component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this situation: A  parent component structured in this way:

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
 })
 export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor() { }

   ngOnInit() {
   }

 }
```

with this html (parent has an ng-content):

```
 <div>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <button>Click to say Hello!!!</button>
 </div>
```

and a child component like this:

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

 @Component({
   selector: "app-child",
   templateUrl: "./child.component.html",
   styleUrls: ["./child.component.css"]
 })
 export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  onSubmit() {
    alert("hello");
  }

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
 }
```

with this html:

```
 <div>I'm child component</div>
```

From the parent component I want to click inside button to invoke onSubmit child function...is this possible?

```
<app-parent>
 <app-child>
 </app-child>
</app-parent>
```

This is a sample; I'm creating a modal that has default buttons: "CANCEL" and "SUCCESS". On the success button I need to invoke one function declared into the childrenComponent.

This is the stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vuctg4

Comment: does the `onSubmit()` need to be in the child? could it be moved to a service?

Comment: There is a number of ways to do this, You can use a service to communicate with the child component and make it execute whatever you want, or use an input setter in the child to execute any function ......

Comment: If your parent has a `@ContentChild(ChildComponent) child;` you can from parent make a `if (this.child) this.child.onSubmit()` or in .html `<button (click)="child && child.onSubmit()"`. It's good check if really exist the "child"

Comment: @Eliseo The name of internal component can change...I can't use contentChild I think...

Comment: it's the name of the "class" of the component. if you has differents components you can try use as many ContentChild you want it or use a service to comunicate between component as there are no relation between both: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: You can use Ngrx as well to communicate between two components

Comment: I partially solved with a service...but If in the children component I have a form with a submit function that has parameters? In the html I defined a form with a function that has the form like input, and inside the function I check if it's valid or not. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can access like that

**app.component.html**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>

<app-parent (clickActionCB)="clickActionCB($event)">
    <app-child></app-child>
</app-parent>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, VERSION, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { ChildComponent } from "./child/child.component";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) childRef: ChildComponent;
  clickActionCB(eventData) {
     this.childRef.onSubmit() ;
  }
}
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-parent",
  templateUrl: "./parent.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./parent.component.css"]
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {}
  @Output() clickActionCB = new EventEmitter<string>();
  clickAction() {
    this.clickActionCB.emit();
  }
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<div>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <button (click)="clickAction()">Click to say Hello!!!</button>
</div>
```

[Live stackblitz URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k3ynjt?file=src/app/child/child.component.html)

Comment: No...it can't work...childcomponent can change...I can't use this solution I think

Answer (score 0):

**child.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-child",
  template: `
    <div>I'm child component</div>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  onSubmit() {
    alert("hello");
  }
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
import { ChildComponent } from "../child/child.component";

@Component({
  selector: "app-parent",
  template: `
    <div>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
      <button (click)="onClick()">Click to say Hello!!!</button>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  @ContentChild(ChildComponent) childRef: ChildComponent;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onClick() {
    this.childRef.onSubmit();
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mteusj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.ts